# How can I get my UDF to work with conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, conditional-formatting

I created a UDF that tests whether a number is between two other numbers. When I try to use it in a conditional formatting formula I get the "This type of reference cannot be used in a Conditional Formatting formula" error.

THE CONDITIONAL FORMATTING FORMULA:

```
=BETWEEN(P11,$N$98,-$N$98)
```

THE USER DEFINED FUNCTION:

```
Function BETWEEN(Num As Long, High As Long, Low As Long) As Boolean

BETWEEN = Num <= High And Num >= Low

End Function
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `AND`? Even better, you can simplify with `ABS` here. `=ABS(P11)<=$N$98`.

Comment: @BigBen I don't understand your question. Are you asking why I didn't write the formula manually using AND instead of using the UDF? I more interested in why the UDF isn't valid for conditional formatting than how I can make it work with a different formula.

Comment: It works for me.  Not sure why it does not work for you.

Comment: Yeah I thought this was over-engineered, but like Scott says, it's unclear why this isn't working fo ryou.